# Programmatically add the created item name to the site page url

Tags: java, jsp, url-rewriting, liferay, liferay-theme

I have site pages with structure like this:

```
/Collections (main page that appears on main navigation menu)
   /Add Collection (child page that appears as a drop down (hover) on main    navigation menu)
      /General Information (child page of Add Collection that appears as tabbed sub navigation menu below main navigation menu. After adding the collection, I redirect to this page.)
```

So the idea is to add a collection, redirect to the `General Information` page where I show the information about that added collection.

The first and second level pages have `theme1`, while the third level page "General Information" has `theme2`. In the site administration, this third level page has friendly url `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/collections/general-information`

and this is what I am trying to modify programmatically.

In the portlet class after creating a collection, I append `id` parameter to this friendly url
`response.sendRedirect(themeDisplay.getURLPortal()+"/collections/"+"general-information?id="+id);`

and in the `theme2` and `jsp`, I get this `id` to display the `General Information` of appropriate collection.

What I want to do is perhaps modify the friendly url programmatically and accomodate the `collection name` in this url. Something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/collections/{collectionname}/general-information
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you have one _page_ per created collection? Or do you have the same page for all collections?

Comment: I have created a page `general-information` in site administration for collection which I display via theme. This page is based on page template where I put the appropriate portlet. And I display appropriate collection using `id` in theme and portlet's jsp page.

Comment: You could use [FriendlyURLs for portlets](http://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/portlet-friendly-url-mapping-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en). The only problem is, that you would need to exchange "{collectionname}" and "general-information" in the URL.